# *C* I keep running into Address Sanitizer Heap Buffer Overflow in Leetcode

Tags: c, heap-memory, buffer-overflow, address-sanitizer

The problem is to find the longest common prefix in an array of strings ie. [flower, flow, flight]
The code I wrote works when I run it in terminal using gcc but when I try it in Leetcode I get an error? I tried looking it up and I keep getting answers where I'm trying to access memory that isn't there but I don't know where I'm doing that in my code. Can anyone explain it a little better? This is the code:

```
char* longestCommonPrefix(char** strs, int strsSize) {
  char* answer;
  answer = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(strs[0]) + 1);
  strcpy(answer, strs[0]);
  for (int i = 0; i < strsSize - 1; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < strlen(strs[i]) && k < strlen(strs[i + 1]); k++) {
      if (strs[i][k] != strs[i + 1][k]) {
        answer[k] = '\0';
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("%s\n", answer);
  return answer;
}
```

Even if I try just this it's still an heap buffer overflow error:

```
char* longestCommonPrefix(char** strs, int strsSize) {
  char* answer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000));
  
  return answer;
}
```

Edit:
I just found a solution on Leetcode someone posted and it creates an array with malloc with no errors.. If anyone call compare this to mine and let me know why malloc works here and not in my function that'd be great.

```
char * longestCommonPrefix(char ** strs, int strsSize){
    char* output = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    strcpy(output, "");
    if (strsSize == 0) {
        return output;
    }
    int longest = strlen(strs[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < strsSize; i++) {
        if (strlen(strs[i]) < longest) {
            longest = strlen(strs[i]);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < longest; j++) {
            if (strs[i][j] != strs[0][j]) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    return output;
                } else if (j < longest) {
                    longest = j;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    free(output);
    output = (char*)malloc((longest + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(output, strs[0], longest);    
    output[longest] = '\0';
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Are the strings passed via `strs` null terminated? Also in the first code block, I guess you meant `strlen(str[0])+1` instead of `strlen(str[0]+1)`

Comment: I don't know C well enough to answer but I can tell it's coming from strcpy(answer, strs[0]);

Comment: Where do you ensure `answer[k]` isn't going out of bounds?  You're checking lengths of `strs[i]` and `strs[i + 1]`, but that doesn't mean you allocated enough space originally.

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj It was a typo thank you I just fixed it. How can I check if the last symbol of the strings is \0?

Comment: Dude ... whatever's in "strs[0]" ... it better have a terminating character before you try to "malloc()" it's length!!!!

Comment: @g3or3 , does the question in leetcode mention anything about null termination in incoming strings? If not you could check the strlen values, but there is no fool proof way to do this .. because there could be some random bytes which are coincidentally the null character (`\0`).

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj With the test case [flower, flow, flight] strlen values are 6, 4, 6 respectively. The question does not mention anything of the sort either. I edited the original question also to see if I can use an arbitrary number inside of malloc so I don't reference the strings that are being passed down however it still results in a heap buffer overflow.

Comment: malloc() without a matching free() is a heap overflow code smell... it looks like the caller is intended to free() buffer returned by longestCommonPrefix(), if there is nothing that will free that buffer then that is in fact a heap overflow mechanism.

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks. I just edited the question because I tried using an arbitrary number inside of malloc instead of referring to the incoming string but it didn't make a difference. I just tried this line of code char* answer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000)); by itself in the function but I still get heap buffer overflow. Anything else I can try? Thanks again

Comment: @MarkU Thanks for the reply. I just edited the question and added one of the solutions someone else submitted using malloc as well. Can you explain why their code works in a more basic description? I'm new and I'm trying to learn as best I can. Thank you.

Comment: According to [this description of how Address Sanitizer works under the hood](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerAlgorithm), asan works by inserting some diagnostic code in place of each malloc() and free(), marking "poison" memory bumpers around the object on malloc(), and marking the object itself poison on free(). All pointer operations are then checked against the "poison" list. In the example below 'fa' is the poison value...

Comment: Can you edit to show the actual, complete heap-buffer-overflow error message, like the example [here](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerExampleHeapOutOfBounds)? In that example it's indicated the error is in line 3 of function main: "#1 0x417f1c **in main** example_HeapOutOfBounds.cc:3" and "=>0x1c07c0003fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00[fa]fa" where the square brackets indicate reading poisoned memory; showing the actual error message is important to learning how to read what went wrong!

Comment: Your version is bugged when `strsSize == 0`